# How do I detect where a string breaks after it renders in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

This is what the source code looks like without line breaks:

```
 <h1>The way they make a show is, they make a first copy, which is called the pilot.</h1>
```

When the html renders the string breaks onto a new line after the words "pilot"  and "show" due to the width of the h1 tag. how do I wrap each line in a span tag?
[here's a visual reference for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzIvS.jpg)

Comment: What is your end goal? Why do you need to wrap each line in a `<span>`?

Comment: @BenM.. I need to animate each line different..hence the reason for wrapping.

Comment: Why can't you break them in advance?

Comment: You can't (reliably) without Javascript. You have to calculate text width given a viewport (given a style). Each chunk (obviously with different number of characters) wrapped in in a div. How to determine the length? Adding one character at a time until you Overflow. Don't forget to also check for characters break rules (which depends on locale). Possibly a nightmare if you want to do it well.

Comment: @croraf ..I can't because I need to dynamically detect how many words fall into each line due to the width of their parent element - the h1 tag

Comment: One solution may be to wrap each word in a `<span>`, and then analyse its `offsetTop` position against its previous sibling. When it changes, you've found the newline.

Comment: @Adriano .. Thanks for the suggestion. You stated "I can't without Javscript" that's why I need a way to do it with javascript. my exact headache per your suggestion is knowing how many characters fit the specified width before the newline

Comment: @BenM .. brilliant idea... very brilliant. could you please provide a quick code that does this..?

Comment: Oh, there isn't a "quick code" to do it properly! You can, however, find good starting points searching for "Javascript calculate text length"

Comment: @benm you can't for a huge number of reasons. Encoding, surrogates, combined characters, groups and joiners plus character breaking rules. You will badly break anything not in us-ASCII. Calculation has to be done in the real viewport (then you also have to track size changes) and you don't actually need to render the DOM.